# update model after validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Users in my system need to have unique emails. If I try to create a user with an existing email the controller throws an error and will rollback any changes.

I want to update a model record if a dupe email attempt is made. But the rollback is preventing any changes from happening, even if it's in a different record. I've tried `update_attribute`, `update_column` and `save(validate: false)` but none of them work.

**How can I bypass the rollback and make some edits to a (separate) model?**

Comment: At what point are you wanting to update? I can't imaging how to actually create a new record if email is required/unique but it fails uniqueness. But I can think of a way that might work for updating an existing record. You could use the model's errors object to check if the email validation failed, then update your model in a separate request.

For example, you might use `person.errors[:email]` to check for errors on the email attribute of person, and if there are update (for example) the person's email_error attribute.

Comment: Did you try save(validate: false)? Not save(validation: false).

Comment: Ideally it happens in the same request. I'd be editing an existing record and not creating a new one. The rollback seems to rollback any changes made during the request. But I'll settle for any solution at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case `after_rollback` does the trick.

During an `after_rollback` callback I check if user with email is present. If so I assume the rollback was due to a dupe email validation failing and then update the appropriate record.

Comment: I haven't seen the after_rollback callback before. Neat.  I think you could still use the errors object ie `person.errors[:email]` inside the callback to actually check that the person has a dupe email error on it (rather than querying your DB again for a matching email) but I don't know if it would practically make a difference.

Comment: I've been working with rails for 4 years and it's my first time seeing it too. Good call on `person.errors`, definitely a better idea. In my case I update the original record's metadata but checking `person.errors` is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using on: :create option for email validation? With this option, validation executes only in create, and skip in update.

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :create
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe I'm not being clear enough. This wont solve my problem.  I'm trying to do an update during a validation failure and the change isn't sticking.